# How to change server name in apache

Tags: apache

i want to change server name in apache. i know its easy as we can make changes in apache.cnf and httpd.cnf file. But i am tired after make changes in all file. i have checked all files and configuration but its not work only repdirect to another ip worked. So how can i change servername ??

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName xyz.com
SSLEngine On
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/server.key.nopass
</VirtualHost>
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score -2):

This can be achieved by installing Apache mod_security module.

After installation , open the Apache configuration file.

```
$ sudo vi /etc/apache2/apache2.conf     #Debian/Ubuntu 
$ vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf         #RHEL/CentOS/Fedora
```

Now change or add these lines below (make sure to change Tech_Web to any other thing you want to appear to clients).

```
ServerTokens Full 
SecServerSignature “Tech_Web”
```

Finally restart the web server.